# Solidity struct mapping not stored in contract

Tags: struct, mapping, storage, solidity

I read many articles on how to use mappings, mappings in struct and came out with something that should be correct to me, based on a few threads.
I know that since solidity 0.7.0 things have changed with nested mappings in struct and did the following :

```
contract Test {
    constructor() {
    }   

    struct Bid {
        uint auction_id;
        address addr;
        uint amount;
    }   

    struct Auction {
        uint id; 
        string dtype;
        uint start_date;
        uint end_date;
        string label;
        uint price;
        uint amount;
        bool closed;
        mapping(uint => Bid) bids;
        uint bidCount;
    }   

    uint public auctionCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Auction) public auctions;

    function createAuction( string memory plabel, string memory ptype, uint nbhours, uint pprice) external {
        Auction storage nd = auctions[auctionCount];
        nd.id = auctionCount;
        nd.dtype = ptype;
        nd.start_date = block.timestamp;
        nd.end_date = block.timestamp+nbhours*60*60;
        nd.label = plabel;
        nd.price = pprice;
        nd.amount = 0;
        nd.closed = false;
        nd.bidCount = 0;
        auctionCount++;
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine, the `createAuction` transaction is succesful.
When checking on the contract in Ganache, auctionCount is incremented but I have no items added in the `draws`mapping.
I also debugged the transaction with truffle and it goes through the function, assigning values through the execution of `createAuction`, but the changes are not persistent.
I even tried removing one string attribute since I read that when there are 3 it could have been a problem (ok, I have only 2 max ;)).

I must have missed something, but I'm out of options right now.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `auctions` mapping, ensure you use the correct index when accessing mapping items. In your case, the first `Auction` item you add to the mapping will have a `0` index. I tried your contract in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), and everything worked well.

Comment: I do not even try to access actions items, I only try to add one and I check directly the contract on Ganache which states in the "Storage" section : "auctionCount : uint 1" (which is because I called the createAuction and it incremented the count, and "auctions : { mapping 0 items }".

Comment: In Solidity, you can't check how many items have been added and exist on the mapping. The thing is that 'they all exist' at the same time. I believe the Auction you are adding to the mapping exists and with proper values. Just try to access it after added. Read this for more context https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13029

Comment: Indeed, I seem to get the one I added, but with incomplete data, I'll look further into it. Thanks for the help, I thought mapping items would be listed in the contract view in Ganache.

Comment: I have another little problem, the first one I add always has default null values (0, false or '' for strings), the next ones are added ok... any hint ? Thanks again